# can't figure out json elements result

Tags: python, objective-c, json, afhttprequestoperation

**Server side** execute a SQL query (server is written in python) returns a json which looks like this:

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps([{"data":output, "total":theResult}]), content_type ='application/json')
```

`output` is a result return from inner method and is already serialized like this:

```
output = serializers.serialize('json',p_list,fields=('price','publishdate','size'))
```

**Client side** receive successfully the response, `success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)` using `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` and this is what `responseObject` looks like in debug console `(lldb)`

```
po responseObject
<__NSCFArray 0x116fa6190>(
{
    data = "[{\"pk\": 817, \"model\": \"xx\", \"fields\": { \"price\": \"3300\", \"publishdate\": \"2014-10-30T00:00:00\", \"size\": 35}}, {\"pk\": 2799, \"model\": \"xx\", \"fields\": { \"price\": \"6250\", \"publishdate\": \"2014-12-08T00:00:00\",\"size\": 0}}]";
    total =     (
       381
    );
}
)
```

in console `po responseObject[0][@"data"][0]` prints the data array and `p responseObject[0][@"total"][0]` print 381 as expected

**The Problem:**

1. in code trying to cast `responseObject[0][@"total"][0]` into integer return a garbage number
2. casting `responseObject[0][@"data"][0]` into `NSArray*` and then trying to perform count or any other operation causes an exception: `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: What does "cast responseObject[0][@"total"][0] into integer" mean and where is the code.

Comment: @Zaph casting means doing `int total = (int )(responseObject[0][@"total"][0])` or  `int total = [responseObject[0][@"total"][0] intValue];`

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem may be that the description method does not quote all strings so 381 may be a string.

Posible solutions (lacking OP code):

if it is really an `int` use:

```
int value = responseObject[0][@"total"][0]
```

if it is really a `string`:

```
NSString *valueString = responseObject[0][@"total"][0] 
int value = [valueString intValue];
```